# How to convert images from the jpg format to ppm(P3)

Tags: jpeg, rgb, image-conversion, ppm

I have recently learned how to read ppm3(P3) images in C++. I just read RGB pixels written in a plain format. I want to convert some certain jpg pictures to ppm3 and then experiment with different things, like identifying numbers there, the circled answers in exam papers, etc.

I have tried this website: https://convertio.co/pdf-ppm/, but it transformed a photo in the P6 format. Could anyone help?

Comment: Have you found or written a library to read `jpg`?  If not I would start by searching for a library.

Comment: Imagemagick [claims](https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) support. You might want to look into it. Also `-Compress None` might help to get P3 specifically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ImageMagick** in the Terminal/shell:

```
magick INPUT.JPG -compress none OUTPUT.PPM
```

If you omit `-compress none` you'll get binary (i.e. P6) PPM output.

---

If using old v6 **ImageMagick**, that becomes:

```
convert INPUT.JPG -compress none OUTPUT.PPM
```

---

All the options, switches, operators and settings for **ImageMagick** are documented [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php).

---

If you want to convert PPM to JPEG, or to PNG, you can just use:

```
magick INPUT.PPM OUTPUT.JPG
```

or

```
magick INPUT.PPM OUTPUT.PNG
```

---

You can also programmatically create a random PPM file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

W=5; H=4
echo "P3\n${W} ${H}\n255" > image.ppm
for ((i=0;i<$((W*H*3));i++)) ; do 
   echo $((RANDOM%255))
done >> image.ppm
```

Then enlarge for easy viewing and make into a PNG:

```
magick image.ppm -scale 200x result.png
```

[image]

Or, the same thing again, nut maybe slightly more elegantly and without creating an intermediate file:

```
#!/bin/bash

W=5; H=4
{
    printf "P3\n${W} ${H}\n255\n"
    for ((i=0;i<$((W*H*3));i++)) ; do 
      echo $((RANDOM%255))
    done
} | magick ppm:- -scale 200x result.png
```

---

If you prefer to use the lighter weight, but far less capable NetPBM tools, it would be:

```
jpegtopnm -plain INPUT.JPG > OUTPUT.PPM
```

Comment: I have no idea what the ImagineMagick is. Do I just have to open the Command Prompt and type "magick INPUT.JPG -compress none OUTPUT.PPM" there? After doing so, it said: "'magick' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.". When I tried "convert INPUT.JPG -compress none OUTPUT.PPM", it said: "Invalid Parameter - -compress". Or do I have to download that ImagineMagick thing?

Comment: You would need to install it. Either from here https://imagemagick.org/ or I believe Windows folk can use Chocolatey https://chocolatey.org/ though I have little idea about Windows.

Comment: I got the impression he wants to do this programatically. If asking for programming suggestions or how to use ImageMagick is an answer then it's off topic as not a programming question or answer.

Comment: @Rob I don't think that's correct. There's a legitimate and popular [imagemagick] tag with 9,000 questions on **ImageMagick**. There is a separate [magick++] tag for programmatic access from C++. If running `sed`, or `awk` or `tr` to transform/convert text from one format/layout to another is programming, then so is running **ImageMagick** to transform images.

Comment: Writing programs that interact with ImageMagick is fine. Just running it by itself is off topic. There are also a lot of systemd and iptables questions here. Most of them are off topic and get closed for the same reason. I haven't seen anything programming related here.

Comment: Mark, can you show the other direction?  --- i.e.,how to read a P3 file into Imagemagick. Perhaps the OP wanted to know how to convert from P3 to some other binary image format.

Comment: @Rob, for my part, I do not think it is off-topic.

Comment: @Rob Please don't underestimate the programming capabilities (FFTs, morphology, colourspace transformations, quantisation, template matching, animation, affine transformations etc) available and programmable from the command line within **ImageMagick** just because this question happens to be at the simpler end of the spectrum. And I stand by my earlier comments about `sed` and `awk`.

Comment: sed and awk are programming. ImageMagick, which I have used for 20 something years, is a program, as is LibreOffice and Photoshop though IM can be used with code. All are off topic here unless they involve programming. @fmw42

Comment: Let's agree to disagree, else we'll get told off for misusing comments.

Answer (score 0):

For parsing pixels P6 is probably more useful for binary apps like C
P3 is about 4 times bigger than P6

both P3 and P6 are uncompressed format 1 entry = one pixel component
normally 3  components = 1 pixel (rgb) here is a white cow in a snowfield

[image]

each `255`  on the Ascii =`ÿ` in the binary thus faster to count one byte text `ÿ` than 4 byte `255`  the main advantage for P3 is when using an ascii editor to fettle the values as number key inputs (modify lower order numbers as 000 - 031 control code values becomes a problem in text editors)

SAFE binary bytes were used for Ansi Art as here this is a binary.ppm (just using safe non control codes.
[image]

The binary version (P6 uncompressed) is most easily generated For PDF users by xpdf or poppler pdftoppm (one single executable no real need for more than that).
http://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html

**For Jpeg you can use jpegtopnm as described in other answer by Mark**
https://sourceforge.net/projects/netpbm/files/
for docs and other info see https://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/
for  binaries on windows the Cygwin / GNUwin32 ports may be useful but older 2005 https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/netpbm.htm **One exe & 4 dlls**

[image: ![enter image description here]

for better description see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#File_formats
for windows related viewing see https://github.com/vbaderks/netpbm-wic-codec and also possibly **conversion** https://github.com/peirick/ZackViewer